# Convert non-montone to monotone data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains repeated measurements for the same subject over time. What I want to find is an easy way to convert these data from non-monotone missing to monotone missing.

e.g. id 1 is monotone: 1,NA,NA,NA
id 3 is non-monotone: 0,NA,0,0
id 4 is non-monotone: 1,1,NA,1

I would like id=3 to be Y=c(0,NA,NA,NA) and id=4 to be Y=c(1,1,NA,NA).

Suggestions?

A toy dataset is included:

```
 df=structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Y = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L), X = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), t = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", 
"Y", "X", "t"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `is.na <-` and that `cumsum` propagates `NA` values:

```
df <- within(df, Y <- ave(Y, id, FUN = function(x) {
  is.na(x) <- is.na(cumsum(x))
  x
}))

df[order(df$id),]
#    id  Y X t
# 1   1  1 5 1
# 5   1 NA 3 2
# 9   1 NA 8 3
# 13  1 NA 3 4
# 2   2  1 6 1
# 6   2  1 5 2
# 10  2  1 9 3
# 14  2  0 4 4
# 3   3  0 7 1
# 7   3 NA 6 2
# 11  3 NA 1 3
# 15  3 NA 5 4
# 4   4  1 8 1
# 8   4  1 7 2
# 12  4 NA 2 3
# 16  4 NA 6 4
```

Comment: plus one. you could also use `replace` to make it a one-liner: `replace(x, is.na(cumsum(x)), NA)`

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df$newcol<-ave(df$Y,df$id,FUN=function(x) NA^is.na(cumsum(x))*x)
#   id  Y X t newcol
#1   1  1 5 1      1
#2   2  1 6 1      1
#3   3  0 7 1      0
#4   4  1 8 1      1
#5   1 NA 3 2     NA
#6   2  1 5 2      1
#7   3 NA 6 2     NA
#8   4  1 7 2      1
#9   1 NA 8 3     NA
#10  2  1 9 3      1
#11  3  0 1 3     NA
#12  4 NA 2 3     NA
#13  1 NA 3 4     NA
#14  2  0 4 4      0
#15  3  0 5 4     NA
#16  4  1 6 4     NA
```

Comment: As long as you sort the dataframe on id and time, then these both work. +1